# Kaa C SDK documentation

Tags: kaa

Kaa C SDK documentation link http://kaaproject.github.io/kaa/doc/client-c/latest/index.html?src=contextnav seems to be broken.

Are there any updates ?

Can anyone help me to find the Kaa c SDK documentation ?

Answer (score 1):

Kaa C SDK documentation has moved to http://kaaproject.github.io/kaa/autogen-docs/client-c/v0.9.0/.

The latest version (as of Nov 2016) is available at http://kaaproject.github.io/kaa/autogen-docs/client-c/v0.10.0/.

I have opened an issue to fix broken links as well: [JEK-6](http://jira.kaaproject.org/browse/JEK-6).